# http to https, www to non www and respect urls

Tags: .htaccess, https, no-www

I want to redirect http to https and www to non www.

**Cases:**

```
http://example.com/my/url
http://www.example.com/my/url
https://example.com/my/url
https://www.example.com/my/url
```

**Result**

```
https://example.com/my/url
https://example.com/my/url
https://example.com/my/url
https://example.com/my/url
```

**My current htaccess file:**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%1/$1 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

**Problem:**

It redirects to https://example.com/index.php.

I want it to respect the url https://example.com/my/url.

I've found many questions but I have not yet found a complete solution. In fact, the htaccess code above was the only one that worked quite well out of like 10 tries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this single rule for removing `www` and `http -> https`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# rest of rules go here ....
```

If you have an issue with too many redirects, try to replace the second line with:
    `RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on`

It is **important to keep this rule as your very first rule** and clear your browser cache before testing.

Comment: Nice to have it all in one rule. I think the solution was to put it before any other rules. Thanks!